# XPath - Get node that only has children with specific attribute

Tags: xpath

I have an SVG document that contains nodes similar to the following:

```
<item>
    <g>
        <path fill="#FFFFFF" ... ></path>
        <path fill="none" ... ></path>
        <ellipse fill="none" ... ></path>
    </g>
    <g>
        <path fill="none" ... ></path>
        <path fill="none" ... ></path>
        <ellipse fill="none" ... ></path>
    </g>
    <g>
       <path fill="#FFFFFF" ... ></path>
       <path fill="#FFFFFF" ... ></path>
       <ellipse fill="#FFFFFF" ... ></path>
    </g>
</item>
```

What I'm trying to do is only select the `<g>` nodes that ONLY contain children that have the `fill="none"` attribute. So I'm trying to find an XPath that only matches the second `<g>` node in my example.

I've done my share of googling and searching on stack overflow and nothing seems to work.

The closest one that I thought SHOULD work is giving me an error saying it's not a valid XPath Expression in Google Chrome's developer tools using the `$x()` helper.

`*[name()="g" and descendants::*[@fill="none"]]`

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
*[    name()="g"
  and descendant::*[@fill="none"]
  and count(descendant::*[@fill="none"]) = count(descendant::*)
 ]
```

Comment: This still selects `<g>` nodes that contain a `fill="none"` as well as `fill="#FFFFFF"`.